# increasing count on scrollViewDidScrollToTop

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int scrollCount = 0;

    scrollin.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"didScroll - %i",scrollCount];

    scrollCount++;
}
```

Always getting didScroll - 0;
Shouldn't it inc. as this method gets called when every scroll ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrollCount` will be initialized each time the method is called, which means it will always be 0, and therefore display 0. If you want the `scrollCount` to live forever in your function, you should make it static. You could do something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    static int scrollCount = 0;
    scrollin.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"didScroll - %i",scrollCount];
    scrollCount++;
}
```

This way, the `scrollCount` will only be initialized once, and it will increment each time the method gets called.

The other way, is to keep track of the `scrollCount` in some sort of class variable, but that's bad practice in my opinion, if you will only use it inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

Define this  `int scrollCount;` in .h and assign it in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   scrollCount = 0;
  }
```

remove int scrollCount;  from the place where you are using it;